# Assign value for specific character strings across columns in R

Tags: r

Working in R.

I have the below dataset and want to assign all "Orange" and "Orange" values to group 1 and all "A" & "B" values 2, the rest will be 3. How do I do this for all columns that contain "Sname" in their column name (ex. column names 3Sname1, 12SName15,etc).

```
df <- data.frame(id = paste0("ID",1:4),
                 Sname1 = c("Apple", "Orangee", "ORANGE", "ornage"),
                 Sname2 = c("Apple", "Orangee", "ORANGE", "ornage"),
                 "6Sname3" = c("Apple", "Orangee", "ORANGE", "ornage"),
                 other = LETTERS[1:4])
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that can easily be extended to cover more types than just apples and oranges:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  # select the target columns:
  mutate(across(matches("Sname"),
                # match variants of "apple" case-insensitively and
                # convert them to 1, all others to 2: 
                ~ifelse(str_detect(., "(?i)^ap"), 1,
                        # match variants of "orange" case-insensitively and
                        # convert them to 2, all others to 3: 
                        ifelse(str_detect(., "(?i)^or"), 2, 3))))
   id Sname1 Sname2 X6Sname3 other
1 ID1      1      1        1     A
2 ID2      2      2        2     B
3 ID3      2      2        2     C
4 ID4      2      2        2     D
```

If you have more types than just apples and oranges, then match them in this way using the case-insensitive flag `(?i)`, a *'core'* pattern that will be found in all/most variants (e.g., the pattern `^ap` will match "apple", "aple", "appel", "apples", "appels", and more) as well as *nested* `ifelse` clauses

Comment: That's awesome thanks, and how would I save this in a new column please?

Comment: Do you mean "how can I save this in a new data frame?". That's easy: just assign the whole thing to a new data frame; e.g., `df_NEW <- df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("Sname"),
                ~ifelse(str_detect(., "(?i)^ap"), 1,
                        ifelse(str_detect(., "(?i)^or"), 2, 3))))`

Comment: I would like to save it in a new column in the same dataframe. So basically I want to assign the pharmacological medications these values to be able to analyse but still keep the original medication names.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it", what do you mean by "one column" (we have three "Sname" columns)? I guess it would be helpful if you posted an expected output